# Flutter - Unrecognised app. Please make sure that you trust this app before proceeding

Tags: flutter, google-pay

I Am trying to implement Google Pay on my flutter with the below code.

```
  void onButtonPressed() async{
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Fetching";});
    try {
      await GooglePay.openGooglePaySetup(
          price: "0.5",
          onGooglePaySuccess: onSuccess,
          onGooglePayFailure: onFailure,
          onGooglePayCanceled: onCancelled);
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Done Fetching";});
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Failed Fetching";});
    }

  }

  void onSuccess(String token){
    setState((){

      Navigator.popUntil(
          context,
              (_) => !Navigator
              .canPop(
              context));

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          new CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext
              context) =>

                  userNoteHome()));

      _googlePayToken = token;


    });
  }

  void onFailure(){
    setState((){


      showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return CupertinoAlertDialog(

              title: Text("Payment Failed",style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

              content: Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),child:Text("Will you like to try again?",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {

                       onButtonPressed();
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();


                    },
                    child: Text('Yes',style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),


                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                     // onButtonPressed();
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();


                    },
                    child: Text('No',style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),

              ],
            );
          });


      _googlePayToken = "Failure";


    });
  }

  void onCancelled(){


    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Cancelled";


    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(

            title: Text("Payment Cancelled",style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),),
            content: Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),child:Text("Are you sure you want to cancel payment?",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),)),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {

                   // onButtonPressed();
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();


                  },
                  child: Text('Yes',style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),)),


              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    onButtonPressed();
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();


                  },
                  child: Text('No',style: TextStyle(color: darkbrown,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),)),

            ],
          );
        });

    });
  }
```

I get this error saying "Unrecognised app. Please make sure that you trust this app before proceeding". At first, I thought it cause it is on test mode and I deployed the application on google play store, and still the error still the same.

Comment: This message typically appears when you are using Google Pay in the `TEST` environment. Usually, if you don't specify an environment, it will default to `TEST`.

Comment: Please how do I change from TEST to LIVE?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Flutter API, but look for a field called `environment` and set it's value to `PRODUCTION`.

Comment: Is the field "Enivironment" meant to be inside my code? Cause there is no field called that in my code.

Comment: It should be part of the `GooglePay` Flutter API. Which API are you using for flutter integration? Does the API documentation mention environment?

Comment: yes I am using flutter integration and my code is attached in my question. It doesn't mention environment in any part of the code.

Comment: Are you using https://pub.dev/packages/google_pay? If so, it looks like there's an [existing issue](https://github.com/baranyildirim/google_pay/issues/1) related to this package. It [doesn't look like it gives you the option to change the environment](https://github.com/baranyildirim/google_pay/issues/1). Consider raising a pull request to apply a fix or choosing a different package.

Comment: How can I pull request to fix? Which other package is available that will use my existing google pay account?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Flutter so I can't recommend an alternative. The issue with the package that I mentioned above is that it doesn't give the developer the option to specify a different environment. The pull request would involve exposing it as a parameter.